# Why can you call BeginInvoke more than once on the same delegate instance?

Tags: .net, multithreading, begininvoke

I thought that calling `BeginInvoke` more than once on the same delegate instance would cause problems, but I tried it out and it works. **Why is that?**

Is the `IAsyncResult` object returned with each `BeginInvoke` called unique instead of each instance of the delegate?

In other words, **do I only need one instance of the delegate to spawn multiple calls to its function?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `BeginInvoke` triggers a new request onto the .net thread pool.

It is perfectly acceptable to call `BeginInvoke` multiple times. Each `IAsyncResult` object is unique to that specific call to `BeginInvoke`.

Just be careful to make sure that you make a matching call to `EndInvoke` for every `BeginInvoke` call you make to make sure the resources are cleaned up.

(Note that each call does not necessarily equate to a thread. `BeginInvoke` passes the requests to the thread pool, which may queue up the requests if all of the threads in the pool are already in use)

Answer (score 3):

Why would it not work? Each time you call it, it will start executing that delegate's actions on a threadpool thread. Yes, each `IAsyncResult` will be independent of the others, representing that asynchronous action.

Yes, you only need one instance of the delegate. Note that delegates are immutable - calling `BeginInvoke` isn't going to change its state. You can safely take a copy of a delegate reference, safe in the knowledge that calling `Delegate.Combine` etc will always create a *new* delegate instance, rather than modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple threads calling the same delegate instance, as per you wish them all to perform the same task, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Each call to `BeginInvoke` will return a different `IAsyncResult`, which can be passed to `EndInvoke` in any order.

You can use the same delegate to make multiple asynchronous calls.